# Why isn't my string being passed properly to this thread-invoked function?

Tags: arrays, string, multithreading, pthreads, cstring

I am working on a multithreaded application in which a client program generates request threads that send strings to a data server program, which answers by sending strings back. Unfortunately, I am having trouble passing data from the client's main function to the function that is invoked by each request thread. In main, I get the request threads going like this (some previous variable declarations not shown):

```
for(int j = 0; j < persons.size(); j++){  //requests deal with imaginary people 
 thread_args* dat = new thread_args; 
 strcpy(dat->str, persons[j].c_str());

 cout << "***I COPIED " << dat->str << " INTO dat->str!!!"<<endl;  //prints as expected 

 pthread_create(&request_thread[j],NULL,&deposit_requests, &dat); 
}
```

Specifically, the structure I am using to pass things with the threads looks like this:

```
typedef struct str_thdata{ 
   char str[100];
} thread_args;
```

Now, in the cout within main ("***I COPIED..."), everything is well and good. The correct value is indeed copied in. When I get to the actual function invoked by the thread, though, the string is lost:

```
    void* deposit_requests(void* str_arg){

      for(int i = 0; i < req_per_person; i++){
         thread_args* data = (thread_args*)str_arg;
         cout << "data->str is " << data->str << endl;  //empty string!!!
         ...       
      } 
   }
```

My only idea is that maybe something is going out of scope? Unless I am being blind here, I don't see where it would happen. Or maybe I need additional casting somewhere? I tried a few variations within the second cout (e.g., using ((thread_args*)data)->str) ), but that didn't seem to work. What is happening to my character array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That &dat you pass in pthread_create is the address of a pointer to a thread_args struct, not the address of a thread_args struct.

Pass dat without the & to pthread_create, and then your code for deposit_requests should run fine.

```
pthread_create(&request_thread[j],NULL,&deposit_requests, dat);
```

Comment: Someone else pointed out, but then their post disappeared, that dat is a local variable on another thread's stack frame. When you pass it using &, you're passing a pointer to an entity that will disappear as soon as the function that called pthread_create ends. However, by passing dat as is, you're passing the pointer to a heap allocated entity that lasts until you free it.

Comment: the 'someone else' maybe realised that it is possible that the function calling pthread_create never ends, in which case the entity will not disappear.  The concern is valid in the general case, but is not a lock.